# Problem upgrading PHP from 7.4.6 to 7.4.12 on Debian

Tags: debian, upgrade, php

I have PHP 7.4.6 running on Debian and want to upgrade to 7.4.12 I run this command

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install php7.4
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'
```

So I tried this

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

planning to run these commands after it

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.4
```

But once I run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and press enter I get

```
  Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
  func(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
  return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 252, in add_ppa_signing_key
  tmp_keyring, tmp_secret_keyring, signing_key_fingerprint, tmp_keyring_dir):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 181, in _recv_key
  "--recv", signing_key_fingerprint,
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
  with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gpg': 'gpg'
```

How can I fix this to upgrade PHP 7.4.6 to 7.4.12 on Debian 10?

Comment: How did you install PHP 7.4.6?

Comment: Actually I didn't I've started making some changes to the Laravel app and planning to upgrade PHP as requested.